# France long stay visa: Should wife and I create two separate online applications?

Tags: france

I am applying for France long-stay visa (under the talent-passport category). In my online application, I mentioned that my wife will be accompanying me. Before scheduling an appointment, should my wife start a separate application? Should she book a separate appointment thereafter?

Thank you.